# Global data buffer pointer to on-chip SRAM

Tags: pointers, memory, embedded, global

I am trying to run [SD/MMC Card Application from NXP.](http://www.nxp.com/documents/software/AN11070.zip) Its for LPC1768 chip.

But I have some trouble with global data buffer.

In file main.c data buffer is a pointer to on-chip SRAM

```
/* data buffer */
uint8_t *buf = (uint8_t *)0x2007C000; // 16KB
```

I compile and run the program in my baord, and program can detect my SD Card and prints "Version 2.0 or later High/eXtended Capacity SD card" through uart.

But then program terminates on the first attempt to access data buffer with error message on gdb

```
lpc1768.cpu -- clearing lockup after double fault

Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x100006fe in SD_RecvDataBlock (buf=0x0, len=512) at sd.c:502
502         buf[i] = SPI_RecvByte ();
```

When print value of buf in gdb, this is what i get

```
(gdb) p buf
$17 = (uint8_t *) 0x0
(gdb) p &buf
$18 = (uint8_t **) 0x10004010
(gdb) p *buf
$19 = 176 '°'
```

Why program doesn't access to pointed memory location 0x2007C000 as indicated in the code?

Comment: What's the `int` size for this compiler?

Comment: I am using uVision 4.74, int size is 32-bits

Comment: One of the following seems to be happening: the runtime isn't initializing `buf` (on some bare board environments, such as what you might run on a LPC1768, you need to make sure there's enough of a runtime to perform global initialization) or something is overwriting the `buf` variable.  Clearly `buf` is not `0x2007C000`. Since you have a working debugger, you should step through the program and look at the value of `buf` to make sure it's initialized at the start of `main()` and then see where it changes.

Comment: those values of buf are from start of main. I think I am missing some project settings in keil. It seems like i need to add some stuff in linker script so compiler specifically assigns value 0x2007c000 to buf. In debug I stopped at the start of main and did (gdb) set buf = 0x2007c000. After I continue code worked :)

Comment: uVision is Keil's IDE, not a compiler.  Since you are using GDB it seems likely that you are using GCC rather than armcc?

Comment: I know uVision is an IDE but it has project settings for auto generated linker script. I use uVision IDE to manage project but I am using openocd and an ft2232 based jtag hardware to debug axf file in my board.

Answer (score 2):

The GDB output indicates that the symbol `buf` within the function `SD_RecvDataBlock()` is *local*; it refers to the *parameter* passed to the function (which is null) and not to your (weakly named) global.